# Regex for multi character strings embedded in rest of match?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

How can I match something like `"AB|CD|EF"` followed by `"12|34"` and get, for instance, `"AB12"` back? If the string was `"zzAB34zz"` I'd get `"AB34"`, `"zzABCD12"` and get `"CD12"`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for named groups here, really:

```
import re
re.search('(AB|CD|EF)(12|34)', 'zzAB34zz').group()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to capture:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(?P<stuff>(AB|CD|EF)(12|34))')

r.findall('__ABCD12__EF34__')
#[('CD12', 'CD', '12'), ('EF34', 'EF', '34')]

r.search('__ABCD12__EF34__').group('stuff')
#'CD12'
```

Named parentheses `(?P<name>...)` can help avoid annoying indexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re ; "".join(re.compile("(AB|CD|EF)(12|34)").search("zAB12z").groups())
```

prints out:

```
'AB12'
```